# fixed effect regression cannot recognize Chinese characters as individual fixed effect

Tags: r, plm

I am running a poisson regression with fixed effect. My individual fixed effects are city names in Chinese characters. However, `pglm` cannot recognize them.

Below is my data set. Column `city` represents cities in this panel data, whereas `time` represents the time variable.

```
 head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 17
  city     time           t  maxt  mint  rain   airp maxairp minairp    rh minhumidity   sun  wind case1    ah case2 trend
  <chr>    <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 安徽亳州 2020-01-24  5.05  7.95  3.3    0   10282.  10300.  10238.  85.5        74.5   0    25       3  5.83   3    0.75
2 安徽亳州 2020-01-25  5.05  7.4   3.3    0   10276   10302.  10255   64          44     5.5  31.5     2  4.36   2    1.75
3 安徽亳州 2020-01-26  2.25  5.35  0.6   82   10246   10272   10228.  83.5        48.5   0    27       0  4.72   0.5  2.75
4 安徽亳州 2020-01-27  1.85  3.6   0.65  20.5 10212.  10238.  10194.  91.5        80     0.5  17       2  5.04   2    3.75
5 安徽亳州 2020-01-28  2.35  8.5  -1.75   0   10201   10210   10188.  82.5        50    72    16.5     7  4.70   7    4.75
6 安徽亳州 2020-01-29  2.2   8.55 -1.75   0   10212.  10224.  10197   83.5        52.5  58    10.5     5  4.71   5    5.75
```

`pglm` gave me errors like followed.

```
reg2 <- df %>% pdata.frame(index = c('city','time')) %>% 
    pglm(formula = case2 ~ t + rh + ah, 
             data = ., family = poisson, effect = 'twoways', model = 'within')

Error in pglm(formula = case2 ~ t + rh + ah, data = ., effect = "twoways",  : 
  object '.' not found
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try the commands stand alone as well (without pipe operator)?